# pip: module installed as editable not found

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I'm trying to install the source checkout of [my own package](https://github.com/martok/py-symcircuit) as an editable package using pip, but it doesn't get picked up as installed.
Yes, there are a whole lot of related questions, but they're mostly about non-standard directory structures. This here seems like it should "just work" and partially even does.

```
# starting from an empty venv:
(env) PS C:\test> pip install -e C:\path\to\my\PySymCircuit
Obtaining file:///C:/path/to/my/PySymCircuit
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting sympy
  Using cached sympy-1.9-py3-none-any.whl (6.2 MB)
Collecting mpmath>=0.19
  Using cached mpmath-1.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (532 kB)
Installing collected packages: mpmath, sympy, SymCircuit
```

Looks good, but:

```
(env) PS C:\test> python -c 'import symcircuit'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'symcircuit'
(env) PS C:\test> pip show SymCircuit
WARNING: Package(s) not found: SymCircuit
```

The link file that is created is correct (as well as the egg-info in the source directory), and when I try to uninstall the package, suddenly it is recognized. Just not when it matters...

```
(env) PS C:\test> cat .\env\Lib\site-packages\SymCircuit.egg-link
C:\path\to\my\PySymCircuit
.
(env) PS C:\test> pip uninstall SymCircuit
Found existing installation: SymCircuit 0.1.0
Uninstalling SymCircuit-0.1.0:
  Would remove:
    c:\test\env\lib\site-packages\symcircuit.egg-link
Proceed (Y/n)? Y
  WARNING: Cannot remove entries from nonexistent file c:\test\env\lib\site-packages\easy-install.pth
  Successfully uninstalled SymCircuit-0.1.0
```

Plain `setup.py develop` produces the same link, also not usable.

What am I missing?

A non-editable install from the same source tree works as intended, so I believe it has something to do with the linking mechanism?

---

**Update**: so apparently the link is just for pip, the important part is that setuptools should add the path to `easy-install.pth`. It doesn't, hence the error message when uninstalling.
Now the question is, why...

---

**Update as requested**:

Local directory structure: `git clone https://github.com/martok/py-symcircuit.git`

```
py-symcircuit
│   LICENSE
│   README.md
│   setup.py
├───.git
├    ...
├───symcircuit
│       __init__.py
│       bode.py
│       spice.py
│       system.py
└───SymCircuit.egg-info
        dependency_links.txt
        PKG-INFO
        requires.txt
        SOURCES.txt
        top_level.txt
```

Setup.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="SymCircuit",
    version="0.1.0",
    author="Martok",
    author_email="martok@martoks-place.de",
    description="Symbolic electronic circuit analysis",
    long_description=open("README.md","rt").read(),
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/martok/py-symcircuit",
    project_urls={
        "Bug Tracker": "https://github.com/martok/py-symcircuit/issues",
    },
    license="MIT",
    classifiers=[...],
    packages=find_packages(),
    python_requires='>=3.6',
    install_requires=[
        "sympy",
    ],
    extras_require={
        "EE": [
            "networkx",
            "numpy",
            "mplotkit"
        ],
    },
)
```

```
Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 23 2018, 23:31:17) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Package          Version  
---------------- ---------
pip              21.3.1
setuptools       59.4.0
```

Comment: I have no problem on Linux. Maybe you have two Python installed and `pip` install in one Python` but you run code with other Python. Pythons don''t share modules. You may try to install with `python -m pip install ...`

Comment: The venv adjusts the path so the tools of whatever version created it are in front. In any case, the `SymCircuit.egg-link` file is in the correct `site-packages` directory, so that can't be it. You're saying this should work? I've tested on two windows machines, same result.

Comment: I got the same prob, which was solved at the `setup.py` level. Could you show us your `setup.py`?

Comment: Version of Python, version of pip, project directory structure, contents of `setup.py`, how did you create the virtual environment - all of this can matter, so please provide it in your question.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I've added the relevant bits. The virtualenv might be distracting from the problem - I get the exact same results working with the global or `--user` site-packages. In any case, just `py -m venv env` followed by updating pip and setuptools, then the bit that's in the question already.
I believe the only thing going wrong is that `setup.py develop` doesn't set up the `easy-install.pth` as it should - if I write that file manually, everything works.