# Editable module ModuleNotFoundError even if installed and running with python in command window

Tags: python, conda, setuptools, mamba

I am going completely mental as I fail to understand and keep my python environment running.

So :

- I have a python environment running under Miniconda 3 and that I manage through an environment.yaml file
- Environment is used to develop within VSCode
- It installs a bunch of external package through conda and then installs my local development package in editable mode (simplified version of the environment.yaml)

```
name: DLL_ETL
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - msys2
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - pandas
  - numpy

  - pip:
    - -e .
    - datatable
```

- I update it regularly through "mamba env update"

However, since today this is what I see :

- Pip states that the package install is sucessful
- In the environment, when running Python from the command line, I can import my package
- Package is installed pointing to the correct location (a one-drive)
- When opening up an interactive window in VSCode with that environment as kernel : package cannot be found

[image: Error messages]

What am I doing wrong?

What I tried :

- Deleting the environment and reinstalling from scratch
- Deleting the pycache and dll.egg-info
- Manually removing and installing again through pip (and not through mamba, even if it runs pip underneath).
- conda list shows the package as properly installed

As can be understood :

- Yes I am running a virtual environment
- Yes I am in the correct directory (especially when updating through environment.yaml)
- Even when manually installing
- Yes the directory with my local install is in my Python path and python is running

[image: Python path]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the solution, but no idea why. I found a comment somewhere (I believe : [pip: module installed as editable not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70148382/20716078)) that there is an issue in how some files are created when installing as editable.

More specifically, when installing as editable, two files are created :

> - ___editable___dll_etl_1_0_0_finder.py
> - **editable**.dll_etl-1.0.0.pth

both in the environment

> Miniconda3\envs\DLL_ETL\Lib\site-packages

When comparing two environments I have, I noticed that the .pth created in the one that broke was not formatted similarly, the .py didn't even exist. More specifically

**The original file**

[image: Original]

**What it should look like**
[image]

When creating the files manually, everything seems to work fine. I haven't tried to update since. Likely it's an issue with setuptools if I understand correctly.

Answer (score -1):

- *Restart* the jupyter kernel.

  [image]
- Add the path to the package above the `import` statement.

  ```
  import sys
  // path is the directory where the package is located, not the full path of the package
  sys.path.append("path/to/package")
  import dll_etl
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the time to look at my question, however : I restarted the kernel as I tried several times the install/uninstall my packages and reboot my laptop/VSCode. Good suggestion through. For the sys : as stated, the path is correctly in python path

Comment: Did you add code to test? It is best not to contain spaces in the package path you installed. In addition, as my answer said, add the directory where the package is located (excluding the package level), not the full path of the package.

Comment: Hey
Yes. Adding a relative path did not fix the problem. I managed to find to root cause, it's in the paths created by pip during the install as editable, more specifically : 

- two files are created : 
  - Miniconda3\envs\DLL_ETL\Lib\site-packages\__editable__.dll_etl-1.0.0.pth
  - Miniconda3\envs\DLL_ETL\Lib\site-packages\__editable___dll_etl_1_0_0_finder.py

When comparing with my other env, I noticed only the first existed with a link to the location on my HDD instead of "import __editable___dll_etl_1_0_0_finder; __editable___dll_etl_1_0_0_finder.install()"

No idea why.

Comment: Yes. I am planning to. Just have to find the time to properly answer and formulate it :-) Screenshots take a while.

Comment: Hi, adding to path is not a desirable answer as installing is supposed to add it to python's import path itself. This was an issue in the setuptools' generated file which was supposed to do this.